# How to draw a circle in React VR?

Tags: react-360

I tried this but get an error "TypeError: this._viewCreator[type] is not a function".

Should I not import from React Native or use another library?

```
import {ART} from 'react-native'

const {
  Shape,
  Path,
} = ART

class Circle extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {radius, ...rest} = this.props

    const circle = Path()
      .move(radius, 0)
      .arc(0, radius * 2, radius)
      .arc(0, radius * -2, radius)

    return <Shape {...rest} d={circle} />
  }

...

<Circle radius={10} fill={blue} />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Cylinder` with 0 `dimHeight`:

```
 <Cylinder
   radiusTop={1}
   dimHeight={0}
   segments={32}
 />
```